# How to write a CREATE TABLE for SQL Server without encountering a syntax error?

Tags: sql-server

```
CREATE TABLE member 
(
    member_id member(10) 
        constraint member_member_id_pk PRIMARY KEY;
    last_name varchar2(25) 
        constraint member_last_name_nn NOT NULL;
    join_date DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE
        constraint member_join_date_nn NOT NULL;
)
```

I am not sure what is wrong, I always get missing right parenthesis at line 3.

Comment: please change the title of the question. It should be a brief of your question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You **must not** use `;` at the end of each line!! Use a `,` (comma) instead, except on the last line (before the `)`).

Also, for the `NOT NULL`, don't define an explicit constraint - on the other hand, for the **default** value for `join_date`, you *should* define an explicit constraint.

And the expression to use for that default constraint should be `SYSDATETIME()` for T-SQL - not `SYSDATE()` ....

```
create table member 
(
    member_id member(10) 
        constraint member_member_id_pk PRIMARY KEY,
    last_name varchar2(25) NOT NULL,
    join_date DATE NOT NULL
        constraint df_member_join_date DEFAULT (SYSDATETIME())
)
```

And last but not least - [this here is the **official** MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979.aspx) for `CREATE TABLE` where you find all these details - and more - please **consult it** next time you need to know something like this!

Comment: Thank you for prompt reply. Sure , i will consult the documentation first  next time.

Comment: @LooChunMeng: if this answer helped you solve your problem, then please [**accept this answer**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/153998). This will show your appreciation for the people who *spent their own time to help you*.